# How to define 2 sets of profiles in pom.xml?

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml

I need to have a 2-dimensions profiles organisation in my pom.xml.

The project is about a fatclient app that comes in different flavours. Each flavour comes a slightly different set of dependencies, internalization files, splash screen, ...
This is one dimension of the profiles.

I also build the app for different os: windows, linux, mac.
This is the 2nd dimension of the profiles. And some stuff must change depending on the target (e.g. for windows, I build a ZIP file, while for linux and mac, I build a TAR.GZ file)

My approach for resolving this is by using the pom.xml profiles for the flavours, and to use the .m2/settings.xml profiles for the os target.
It works, but it isn't nice. Because the .m2/settings.xml should be limited to config specific to the user and not contain "build logic".

I'd like to "transfer" the "build logic" that I put .m2/settings.xml into the pom.xml.
But I don't want to have 1 Profile level having (#Flavours x #Os) profiles (e.g. flavour1-os1, flavour1-os2, ...)

Is this achievable ? Is there a way to implement this 2 levels of profiles in the pom.xml ?

Comment: What kind of differences are those between the os's ? You have written resources and dependencies? So make different modules in your build with the different deps ...

Comment: The difference is at the level of the JRE to include into the final builts.

Comment: Using maven-assembly-plugin and define the JRE as a package in your repository manager ...than this can be handled without any profile and makes maintenance easier... instead of using profiles...because in case of profiles you can't really make releases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare one profile for each flavour:

```xml
    <profile>
      <id>flav1</id>
      ...
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>flav2</id>
      ...
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>flav3</id>
      ...
    </profile>
```

and one for each OS:

```xml
    <profile>
      <id>win</id>
      ...
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>linux</id>
      ...
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>mac</id>
      ...
    </profile>
```

[Activate them](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#details-on-profile-activation) individually by e.g:

```bash
mvn -P flav1, linux ...
```